# React Router location changes automatically

Tags: router, javascript

from the photo you will notice that update location action is called so many times and this action is responsible for listening to the react router location and change the redux state to be able to use it inside a connect wrapped component as I can't use the router location directly inside the connected components but the starnge thing is that the location here is changed like 5 times while it is supposed to be changed only once since I was on the login page and it redirects me to the home page (this console is from the home page) please help 
[logger actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKsYw.png)

Comment: btw I use lazy loading in react I think that could be the cause of the problem I fired an issue here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6561